# No matcing function to call to class::class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Im new to c++ and am working on a pacman prototype.
While trying to grasp the concept of polymorphism i came accross this problem.
Every time i try to create a constructor or an object for Ghost and ScaredGhost classes i end up with the No matcing function to call to class::class error.

Heres my header file :

```
    class Enemies : public Window
    {
        public:
            Enemies(const Window &window,int w,int h,int x,int y);
            virtual ~Enemies();
            virtual void EnemyDraw() = 0;
        protected:
            int gh,gw;          //Height width
            int gx,gy;             // x and y

    };

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    class Ghost : public Enemies
    {
        public:
            Ghost();
            void EnemyDraw();
    };
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    class ScaredGhosts : public Enemies
    {
        public:
            void EnemyDraw();
    };
```

and the implementation :

```
Enemies::Enemies(const Window &window,int w,int h,int x,int y):
    Window(window), gw(w), gh(h), gx(x),gy(y)
{
    //ctor
}
 Enemies::~Enemies(){}

//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________

void Ghost::EnemyDraw()
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.w = gw;
    rect.h = gh;

    rect.x = gx;
    rect.y = gy;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,255,0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer,&rect);

}
    Ghost::Ghost()
    {
    }

//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________

void ScaredGhosts::EnemyDraw()
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.w = gw;
    rect.h = gh;

    rect.x = gx;
    rect.y = gy;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,255,255,0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer,&rect);
}
```

This is just the base of this class but I cannot proceed without overcoming this problem.

Comment: It' abd in general class names should not be plural.s hard to see how `Enemies` can be a `Window.`  Also, I would suggest writing your game without using inheritance - inheritance is  vastly over-used by beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ghost::Ghost()
{
}
```

This constructor implicitly tries to call the no-argument constructor of all of its base types.  However, there is no no-argument constructor of `Enemies`, from which `Ghost` inherits, so this call fails.  (This is where the "no matching call to Enemies::Enemies()" comes from -- the compiler is telling you that `Ghost::Ghost()` is trying to call this constructor, but it doesn't exist.)

One way to resolve this problem would be to accept the same arguments in the `Ghost` constructor and forward them:

```
class Ghost : public Enemies {
    public:
        Ghost(const Window &window,int w,int h,int x,int y);
        // ...
};

Ghost::Ghost(const Window &window,int w,int h,int x,int y)
    : Enemies(window, w, h, x, y)
{
}
```

You need to do the same thing with `ScaredGhost`.

C++11 permits you to inherit constructors like this, which is substantially easier and far less error-prone:

```
class Ghost : public Enemies {
    public:
        using Enemies::Enemies;
        // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It helped

Comment: @JuliusTumas if it helps, consider accepting the answer